# Como mostrar el valor de 1 de un check como un texto

Tags: php, ajax

Cambiar valor = 1 por "Activo" o valor = 0 por "Inactivo"

```js
if (isset($active) == 1) {
  $is_active = "Activo";
}
elseif(isset($active) == 0) {
  $is_active = "Inactivo";
}
```

Así como esta muestra todos como Activos y debería haber uno inactivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tengo una duda aqui si esta bien con doble 'e' $activve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que chequear dos condiciones, que el valor exista **"Y"** que sea igual a 1.  Asi:

```
if (isset($active) && $active == 1) {
  $is_active = "Activo";
}
elseif(isset($active) && $active == 0) {
  $is_active = "Inactivo";
}
```