# Mostrar Check guardados en Base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Estoy guardando los valores de un checkbox en mysql pero necesito que cuando lo muestro si guarde 1 aparezca activado pero si guarde 0 que no aparezca chequeado

Asi lo guardo

```js
$id = $_POST['mod_id'];
$name = $_POST["mod_name"];
$code = $_POST["mod_code"];
$active = isset($_POST["mod_active"]) ? 1 : 0;
$user_update = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$date_update = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

var_dump($code, $name, $user_update, $date_update, $active);

if (isset($_POST['active']) == 1) {

  $sql = "UPDATE way SET code=\"$code\",name=\"$name\", user_update=\"$user_update\", date_update=\"$date_update\" where id = $id";
} else {

  $sql = "UPDATE way SET code=\"$code\",name=\"$name\", active=\"$active\", user_update=\"$user_update\", date_update=\"$date_update\" where id = $id";
}
```

Así lo quiero mostrar, pero no funciona

```js
if (isset($active) && $active == 1) {
  $is_active = "Activo";
}
elseif(isset($active) && $active == 0) {
  $is_active = "Inactivo";
}
```

Comment: Creo que te falta un echo asi: `?  echo 'checked' : echo '1';`

Comment: no si lo pongo así da error, lo que necesito es que los checks que guarde me los muestre marcados cuando vuelvo abri el formulario

Comment: Volviste a cometer el mismo error de esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182853/como-mostrar-el-valor-de-1-de-un-check-como-un-texto/182855#182855

Comment: i suggest use this: <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1">...for validate in php: if ($_POST['test'] == '1'){..do something..active...}else{..inactive..}

Comment: on the return from your db similar to this:....<input type="checkbox" name="state" id="state" value="1" <?php echo ($dbvalue['state']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?>>

Answer (score 0):

isset() se usa para saber si una variable es definida o es null, en tu caso quieres saber si la variable tiene valor 1 o diferente de 1.

Si necesitas validar si la variable esta definida primero valida con el isset y verifica que el valor tiene tu variable.

```
if ($_POST['active'] == 1) {
   $sql = "UPDATE way SET code=\"$code\",name=\"$name\",
   user_update=\"$user_update\", date_update=\"$date_update\" where id = $id";
} else {
  $sql = "UPDATE way SET code=\"$code\",name=\"$name\", active=\"$active\", user_update=\"$user_update\", date_update=\"$date_update\" where id = $id";
}
```

Comment: Gracias con eso no tengo problema es a la hora de mostrar el check como activo por que se guardo como activo

Comment: <?php if ($active == 1) {
                                        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="mod_active" checked />Activo</label>';
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="mod_active" />Activo</label>';
                                    }
                                    ?>

Comment: Tampoco me sirvió

Comment: el "$active" de mi comentario cambialo por "$_POST['active']"

Comment: tampoco me sirvió